# SMTP server not sending email to the same domain

Tags: iis, smtp

I have my ASP.Net MVC application setup so that it sends emails to a mail pickup directory. I have also Installed a virtual SMTP server on the server. The problem is that emails are being sent to all domains expect to the same domain. I know it is a server setup issue but do not know where to start to look the the issue. My smtp server settings look like this. Email to the same domain are being sent to the queue folder and I do not see any errors being logged in the event viewer.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]

Comment: Just wondering have you got the solution as m getting a bit different error i can only send emails to same domain.

Comment: @Preet, Still have not managed to resolve this.

Comment: ohhh okay, Thanks for reply